# ModelState error on Facebook external authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, configuration, modelstate

I am learning the ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC Framework. I have built a simple App, gave it a name, and am currently working through Microsoft documentation to make it work. My current goal is to set up Facebook external authentication.

I have the Visual Studio's template which includes individual user account authentication and I plan on deploying this application to Azure cloud. I followed all the steps to register my app through Facebook's developer page. I specifically do not want to hard code Facebook's App Id and the secret to the Startup file because I want to implement the Azure key vault to increase security. I'm choosing to use Azure key vault instead of local secrets because I want to deploy this solution to the cloud.

The issue is that if I run the solution, I see the correct button show up to take me to Facebook's authentication. It routes me to their error page, and in the debugger, I see this error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker:Information:
>   Executing handler method
>   RecipeBox3._0.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.ExternalLoginModel.OnPost
>   with arguments (Facebook, /) - ModelState is Invalid

There is no documentation for this error, and I am running in circles trying to find out the reason for this error. Is there any way I could get some assistance?

I have tried tons of research into what Facebook needs to be passed; if they need more than the id and secret, then I can't find anything that says that. I have tried stepping through the steps to find out what data is being passed to Facebook with no luck, it is a lack of fundamental understanding of how ASP.Net Core handles identity and services.

This is the bit in my Startup Config that I call my Facebook class which reads from Azure Key Vault

```
 services.Configure<Facebook>(Configuration);
            services.AddTransient<Facebook>();
            services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
                        {
                            facebookOptions.AppId = Options.facebookID.ToString();
                            facebookOptions.AppSecret = Options.FacebookSecret.ToString();
                        });

            services.Configure<RecipeBox3._0.Services.SendGrid>(Configuration);
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

This is my Facebook class (case matches what is inside key vault exactly)

```
public class Facebook
{
   public long facebookID { get; set; }
   public long FacebookSecret { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: UPDATE: It works if I hard code the ID and secret. So there must be something wrong with the Key Vault retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I had to call the values inside of the KeyVault like this:

```
 facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["facebookID"];
                           facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["FacebookSecret"];
```

So my class wasn't working as intended.